# Finding a certain base change matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation defined by:

$$T(a,b) = (2a+b,a-3b)$$

Let $\alpha$ be the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\gamma$ be the basis $\{(1,1),(1,2)\}$. Find the matrix $A$ of $T$ relative to $\alpha$, the matrix $B$ of $T$ relative to $\gamma$, and a matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ = B$

My thoughts:

So to find a matrix $A$ relative to $T$, we need to find the columns of $A$. The image of each basis element of $\alpha$ under $T$ wil be the columns of $A$. The same goes for finding a matrix of $T$ relative to $\gamma$. Is this correct?

I do not, however, know how to find $Q$ and would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct, however, for the standard basis, you can deduce the matrix $A$ directly from the equations:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-3\end{bmatrix}.$$

As to the change of basis matrix fromù  the standard basis to the basis $\gamma$, their columns are the coordinates of the vectors of $\gamma$ in the standard basis, namely
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Last, there's a formula to deduce $T$ from $A$:
$$T=Q^{-1}AQ.$$

Answer (score 1):

To get $Q$ you must express old basis in new one:  $$(1,0)=2(1,1)-(1,2)$$ and $$(0,1)= -(1,1)+(2,1)$$ so $$Q^{-1}=\pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&1}$$